# dojo aspect and key press

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dojo, dom-events

Is there a way to capture a key press event with `dojo/aspect` and `aspect.after`?

I am using a third party Javascript API (ESRI JS API v3.4) that provides a widget for drawing graphics on a map.  The `draw toolbar` widget has an `onDrawEnd` event that provides the shape of the drawn graphic object as a parameter.  I need to determine if the user was pressing the `CTRL` or `SHIFT` key while drawing on the map with this widget, but I use `aspect.after(drawingToolbar, "onDrawEnd", myhandlerfunction, true)` to connect the drawing event.

The only way I know how to determine if a key is pressed is by using an `event` object, which is not provided when using `aspect` like it is with `dojo/on`.

Any ideas how I can determine if a key is pressed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe u musst go another way to catch up a Key-Event.

This is how i catch the "Enter"-Event in a Textbox. When the Enter-Key is hit, the function zoomToAnlage() is called. It's important that this event listener is already loaded in the ini-phase.
Sure, this is not a total resolve for your Question, but maybe it shows a way how you can handle it.

```
    function initKielAnlagenNummernSuchen(){

    queryTaskAnlagenNummern = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(restServicesLocation + NameSearchService + "/MapServer/23");

    queryallAnlagenNummern = new esri.tasks.Query();
    queryallAnlagenNummern.returnGeometry = true;
    queryallAnlagenNummern.outFields = ["ANLAGE"];

    require(["dojo/keys","dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(keys, dom, on){
        on(dom.byId("selectAnlagenNummer"), "keypress", function(evt){
            var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
            if (charOrCode == keys.ENTER) {
                zoomToAnlage();
            }
        });
    });
```

}

Here's a Link to dojo/keys :  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/keys.html?highlight=keys#id2
Regards, Miriam

Answer (score 0):

dojo.aspect can't connect to events, only functions. However you should be able to aspect to a function that is handling that event, and steal its args.

```
aspect.after(drawingToolbar, "someHandlerFunctionWithTheEventArg", 
    function(args){
      // access the event from the args here
    }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I gave it a shot, but it didn't work.  If I use `receiveArguments=true` in `aspect.after` on one object is returned which represents the graphic that was drawn on the map.  If I do not add the `receiveArguments` parameter, I get an array of arguments that only contains the single object.  I'm starting to think I should just connect to the `KeyPress` event of my map at the same time I connect to `onDrawEnd`.